# How to clean up this strange PHP code?

Tags: php

this script outputs the birthdays as headlines and the customer(s) below.

So the output is "grouped" by the date of birth.

```
echo "<div>";

foreach(pdo_query("SELECT customer, birthday FROM table ORDER BY birthday ASC", array($empty)) as $row)
    {
        if(!isset($birthday) or $birthday != $row['birthday'])
            {
                unset($drawline);
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class=title><h1>".$row['birthday']."</h1></div><div class=customer>";
            }

        if(isset($drawline)){echo "<hr>";}

        echo $row['customer']."<br>";

        $drawline = 1;

        $birthday = $row['birthday'];
    }

echo "</div>";
```

'birthday' is a DATE-field in the database.

Between the customers there's always a line (hr), but not after the last customer of a d.o.b.

Example output:

```
<div class=title><h1>1986-10-08</h1></div>
<div class=customer>
Don Foo<br>
<hr>
Joe Bar<br>
</div>

<div class=title><h1>1988-03-18</h1></div>
<div class=customer>
Jane Fonda<br>
<hr>
Elvis Burns<br>
</div>
```

Is it possible to remove the `<div>` and `</div>` outside the `foreach()`?

It produces always an empty `<div></div>`.

Answer (score 2):

I've decided that it's too much hassle on the programmer's mind to see what's happening here, so here is much cleaner version of your code.

```
<?php
$people = pdo_query("SELECT customer, birthday FROM table ORDER BY birthday ASC", array($empty));
if (!empty($people)) {
// Find out people with the same birthday and group them.
$birthdays = [];
foreach ($people as $man) {
    $birthday = $man['birthday'];
        if (empty($birthdays[$birthday])) {
            $birthdays[$birthday] = [];
        }
        $birthdays[$birthday][] = $man['customer'];
    }
// Now let's output everything!
?>
<div>
<?php foreach ($birthdays as $birthday => $customers): ?>
    <div class=title><h1><?= $birthday ?></h1></div>
    <div class="customer">
        <?= implode('<br><hr>', $customers) ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
</div>
<?php } // endif (!empty($people)) ?>
```

Main point of this solution - very simple to understand, uses somewhat templating (you could create one for this little snippet), easy to debug and modify. And yes, it does not output the empty `<div></div>` anymore!

Comment: It might not be enabled by default, so you should mention that short tags `<?=` should be enabled for this code to work.